# Finding time of arrival of signal using GNU radio

Tags: gnuradio, software-defined-radio, localization, usrp

I am sending a repeating BPSK modulated PN sequence signal from a USRP x310 transmitter. I am receiving the sequence with another USRP x310. Both are attached to an octoclock. Is there a way to get the global time when the receiver starts writing to the file sink?

Here is a look at the receiver block diagram:

[image]

Currently, I can use the file metadata sink to get the time it starts writing (starting at 0 sec) and subsequent writes after a number of samples. But it does not give the global time. I eventually want to use this global time measurement to calculate the time difference of arrival at multiple receivers.

Comment: 24 MS/s isn't a valid sampling rate, far as I can tell. It needs to divide the Master Clock Rate of 200 MHz evenly. THis would only work if you set the MCR to say 120 MHz.

Comment: what's "global time"?

Comment: Right, I usually set it to 25M or 20M. When I say global time I mean the coordinated universal time (UTC) or local time (in this case mountain standard)